Convert absolute filesystem path to a file URI in a platform-agnostic way with boost url
The question Convert absolute filesystem path to a file URI in a platform-agnostic way
is six years old and now we have boost url https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/libs/url/doc/html/index.html.
Is it possible to convert the abs path with boost url?
I tried for example this:
boost::url u;
u.set_scheme( "file" );
u.set_path( "c:/path/to/file.txt" );
cout << u << "\n";

The result is:
file:c:/path/to/file.txt
But it should be:
file:///c%3A%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile.txt
You can test it with https://www.urlencoder.org/

That site doesn't convert to URI. It does URL encoding, regardless of input (they even allow you to upload entire files)
As the linked answer also demonstrates no such encoding is required. These are valid output:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/url.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::url url;
    url.set_scheme("file");
    url.set_query("c:/path/to/file.txt");
    std::cout << url << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - scheme: "    << url.scheme()    << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - authority: " << url.authority() << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - path: "      << url.path()      << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - query: "     << url.query()     << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - fragment: "  << url.fragment()  << std::endl;

    url.set_host("localhost");
    std::cout << url << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - scheme: "    << url.scheme()    << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - authority: " << url.authority() << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - path: "      << url.path()      << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - query: "     << url.query()     << std::endl;
    std::cout << " - fragment: "  << url.fragment()  << std::endl;
}

FORCE encoding
You can always insist on doing what you want (even if it's probably not the right thing to do):
boost::urls::encoding_opts opt;
// opt.space_as_plus = true;
std::string s = boost::urls::encode("c:/path/to/file.txt", [](uint8_t ch) { return std::isalnum(ch); });
std::cout << "Forced: " << s << std::endl;

Which will not create an equivalent URI, but does print what you give as example:
Forced: c%3A%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile%2Etxt

Note that since you're not adhering to any URL specification here, it's up to you to decide which characters are actuall unreserved:
std::cout << "Unreserved:      " << boost::urls::encode(p, boost::urls::unreserved_chars) << std::endl;
std::cout << "All:             " << boost::urls::encode(p, [](auto) { return false; }) << std::endl;
std::cout << "Non-punctuation: "
          << boost::urls::encode(p, [](uint8_t ch) { return ch != '%' && std::ispunct(ch); });

Printing
Unreserved:      c%3A%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile.txt
All:             %63%3A%2F%70%61%74%68%2F%74%6F%2F%66%69%6C%65%2E%74%78%74
Non-punctuation: %63:/%70%61%74%68/%74%6F/%66%69%6C%65.%74%78%74

All-in-one link: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a945476e24a46f62

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/file-uris-in-windows

Thank you for the answer.
But the code
#include <boost/url.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::url url;
    url.set_scheme("file");
    url.set_query("c:/path/to/file.txt");
    std::cout << url << std::endl;

    url.set_host("localhost");
    std::cout << url << std::endl;
}

returns:
file:?c:/path/to/file.txt
file://localhost?c:/path/to/file.txt

Why is there a question mark between file: and the rest?
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b98b9cae39ebb7e3
